# Yii CGridView and buttons

Tags: yii, cgridview, cbuttoncolumn

Looking to remove buttons based on data for that row.
[Picture 1 - Normal with all buttons](http://i1304.photobucket.com/albums/s527/goergeducharme/question1a_zps686a951e.png)
To this where the second line has some data in the table that depicts something.
[Picture 2 - With Button removed](http://i1304.photobucket.com/albums/s527/goergeducharme/question1b_zpse412cc07.png)
I have seen how to color the rows which is nice but need to remove buttons as well.  Any thoughts?
(sorry for the external links, still a new user)

Comment: How are you generating those buttons?

Comment: Not using a template at the moment it is the standard build of gridview.  Been playing with the idea of using a template though.

Comment: Take a look at [CButtonColumn::visible](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CButtonColumn#visible) and [CButtonColumn::buttons](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CButtonColumn#buttons-detail)

Comment: Fond this in another post looking for something completely different:[See Here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/12039-remove-disable-the-button-update-in-the-cgridview/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use your data to change visibility of the button columns like this:

replace

```
array(
  'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
),
```

with something like this:

```
array(
  'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
  'template'=>'{view}{update}{delete}',
  'buttons'=>array(
    'update'=>array(
        'visible'=>'$data->cust == "ST50"',
    ),  
  ),  
),
```

but it won't keep the spacing when the button is not visible. I'll leave that to you.
You can customize other attributes of CButtoncolumn here's a couple of refs: [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CButtonColumn) and [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/106/using-cbuttoncolumn-to-customize-buttons-in-cgridview/)

Comment: Thanks, figured out that the $data->(what ever) is what you need to put in there instead of $model or anything else.